# Multiple payments related to multiple customer implementation in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a customer management system for my business and got stuck on the payments entry system. This will run on a local dedicated server and should have only one user so code performance is not really an issue.

Every adult customer who enters the store is given a numbered card (`Card`, for the rest of this question) and his/her ID ( from `Customer` model ) is attached to it by a foreign key relation. There is an "entrance fee subtotal", which is the result of a choice field on `Card` model (there's only two choices and those won't change for a long time) plus kids 'fees'.
This, along with other two kind of models ( `Product` and `Service`), will compose the customer's bill. I have it working just fine, except on the payments registration.
As many Customers may be part of a family, and they may split their total bill quite often, I do believe `Payment` should be a model with an `ManyToManyField` related to `Card` so it could cover multiple payments methods ( treated as another choice field, since it will be either money, credit or debit cards ) but I can't figure it out how to model it neither how to handle it in my view/template.

I'm using django 1.9 & postgres 9.5 & python 2.7.

Bootstrap 3 along with some JS for styling (probably irrelevant). 
Enough said, here's some code:

`models.py`

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #unnecessary but I had already written it
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class Card(models.Model):

    entrance_type1 = 1
    entrance_type2 = 2

    entrance_choices = (
        (entrance_type1, 'Fun'),
        (entrance_type2, 'Really Fun, kinda expensive'),
    )

    entrance_types = {
         1:"Fun",
         2:"Really Fun",
    }

    entrance_fee= {
    'kid':5.0,
    entrance_type1:15.0,
    entrance_type1:35.0,
}

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #Yeah, I do that
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    card_number = models.IntegerField()
    entrance_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=entrance_choices)
    kids_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    id_costumer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    entrances_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    #will be entrance_fee[entrance_type] + entrance_fee['kid'] * kids_number
    status = models.BooleanField(default=1) #should be 0 after payment(s)
```

Anyway, I really need help modelling payments for those. It should contain payment method, date and to which `Card`s it's related to.
I'm already getting ideas on the views/template step so I won't be strict about those on answers.
I do believe my question is kinda fuzzy and confuse, but can't figure how to make it better ( and maybe this is why I can't solve it by myself ) so please comment in your doubts and I'll edit it ( including removing this part when it does improve) after lunch.
Thanks in advance